# Reason to connect a bidirectional tvs diode in paralell with a unidirectional one

Tags: dc-dc-converter, load

I am designing my own high-side smart load switch for my power supply using TPS27SA08 ic.

I decide to investigate how it works this evaluation board https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvubd4b/slvubd4b.pdf?ts=1612274192754&ref_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fpdf%252Fslvubd4
that uses the same ic I mention.

At Vin the board use this components:

[image: board image]

I can not understand the reason why they use a bidireccional tvs diode (D3 https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm6t39ca.pdf)

with a unidirectional one (D4 https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/smcj30a.pdf).

As far as I know with a bidirectional one you obtain the same clamping voltage in both directions. Also this two diodes have different breakup and clamping voltage.

Comment: it would make more sense to me if there was something between them - inductance (even just wire), resistance, series diode, etc. Otherwise the unidir with the smaller Vbr would end up doing all the work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 and D4 in the original design are optional so, you decide which one you need and fit it as necessary. Both are on the PCB for your pleasure. Read the Datasheet carefully and you’ll see what I mean.

> *Transient Protection The HSS-MOTHERBOARDEVM comes with large
> footprints for TVS diodes if they are needed for any transient
> testing. D3 is an SMB footprint while D4, D5, and D6 are SMC
> footprints*

Comment: I recently found the answer. Thanks so much Andy!!. Could you explain me also why at Vout the board use tvs diodes. Are present to prevent reverse battery protection?

Comment: Voltage transients on your output are possible. For instance inductive flyback. It will offer some reverse voltage protection until it burns out.

Comment: Thanks so much Parker!

Comment: @marcosbc D3, D4, D5 and D6 are for transient protection whether it's on the input or the output. If your load is connected on longish cables then fit them due counter back-EMFs when the high side switch disconnects. If there's any doubt about what might be connected to the output i.e. a customer can wire to it then use a fuse and fit an appropriate TVS or zener to protect against potential customer damage.